# show "on hover info" in vscode with keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I trigger the info display via the keyboard ?

Hovering over the sqwiggles with the mouse is a pain.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shortcut CTRL+k i